# Connection error with Tornado Websockets + Django + Azure + Apache

Tags: python, django, sockets, azure

I am running my application with Windows Azure on a Virtual Machine with ubuntu 14.04 lts. I am running my Django application through WSGI on Apache.

Previously i ran django locally with the command "python manage.py runserver", and every thing worked fine when my website connected to my sockets.py file from website.html.

1. I am running Django through Apache on public ip port 80
2. I am running the sockets.py separately in a terminal through Putty
3. I am reading the error through the Google Chrome console

Suddenly this error occurs:  **Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.** whenever i try to connect to the socket.

After a while my page response with: failed: **Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT**

**website.html js:**

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://10.77.22.74:1339/ws");

function load_all() {
    target = "load_all"
    ws.send(target)
}

ws.onmessage = function(evt) { 
console.log(evt.data)
}
```

The ip is my internal ip on my virtual machine.

**sockets.py**:

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True

    def open(self):
        print 'new connection'

    def on_message(self, message):

         self.write_message(message)


    def on_close(self):
      print 'connection closed'


application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/ws', WSHandler),
])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(1339)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

1. I have tried to change the `http_server.listen(1339)` to `http_server.listen(1339, adress='10.77.22.74')` (sockets.py)
2. I have tried using my public ip and opening a port through tcp (endpoints) and adjusting the scripts after that (sockets.py & website.html)
3. I have tried running with the localhost & 127.0.0.1 (sockets.py & website.html)
4. I have tried with ws & wss

I still get the error for some reason, do i need to give Apache (www-data) some permissions to connect to the sockets.py?

Which IP should i use, both on socket.py and website.htm?

### Solved

Turn out Tornado is listening to all IP:s if you not specify the adress in the socket server. I opened a port on the public IP and used that IP for my javascript socket connection.